# Tinymce is not Displaying at at all

Tags: tinymce

Hy There...!

I have some problems when its come to Jquery ..............

Here i am trying to use TinyMCE Text Editor... I had download its Js File and some code with it mention it in there site...

But When i see my index.HTML it is all Blank.....

Which i don't understand Please Any Help or hint will be appreciated........

Thanks in Advance ... Here Is The Code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
 });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="index.html">
    <textarea name="content" style="width:100%" class="mceEditor"></textarea>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is TinyMCE being loaded correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not linking the `tinymce.js` file correctly. Make sure it's linked correctly relative to the directory of `index.html` file.

I used the same markup you provided and made it work in jsFiddle using the script from TinyMCE CDN.

http://jsfiddle.net/AHXXT/